Laravel filament is unable to save nested repeater items
In Laravel filament V3, I am creating an StudentResource with the below relationships:
STUDENT --hasMany--> ENROLLMENTS -- hasOne --> STUDENT_FEE -- hasMany --> STUDENT_FEE_INSTALLMENTS

So I have used two Repeaters, one for relationship enrollments and another one for studentFeeInstallments. On saving student resource, it works if I remove the 2nd Repeater. That is I can save relationship upto studentFee. If I add the repeater for studentFeeInstallments then, while saving,  the filament is treating studentFeeInstallments as a field name of StudentFee model. It throws the error:
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "studentFeeInstallments" of relation "student_fees" does not exist LINE 1: ...nt_fees" set "pay_mode" = $1, "fee_payable" = $2, "studentFe... ^
update
  "student_fees"
SET
  "pay_mode" = FI,
  "fee_payable" = 1200,
  "studentFeeInstallments" = [ { "serial_no": "7",
  "amount": "1200",
  "interval": "20",
  "interval_unit": "Days",
  "due_date": "2024-04-29" } ],
  "updated_at" = 2024 -04 -15 19: 10: 45
WHERE
  "id" = 2

So doesn't filament allow to use nested repeaters?
How do I save  studentFeeInstallments relationship on Creating/Updating StudentResource?
Note: For Layout I use Wizard to separate student details  step with enrollment.
